# Android Annotation @AfterViews not called on activity resume

Tags: android, android-annotations

The first time I load my activity, I create the view with the @AfterViews annotated method. But when I come back on this activity, @AfterViews is not called again. I need to put the code which refresh the view in onResume().

The problem is that in this case the first time I load the activity I execute the @AfterViews annotated method AND the onResume().

Do you have a solution in order to call only @AfterViews on first load, and onResume() when the activity resume ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`@AfterViews` methods are not called after in `onResume()`. `@AfterViews` are called when the view hierarchy has been created: in case of `Fragment`s in `onViewCreated()`, in case of `Activity` in `onCreate()`.

If you have to update your views in `onResume()`, just override that as usual.

Comment: I understand what you mean but actually my @AfterViews method is call in onViewCreated() (maybe because it is a SherlockFragmentActivity), and when I resume the activity the view is refreshed twice. (one by   onViewCreated() and the other one in onResume() )

Comment: This is not really related to `@AfterViews`. You have to deploy some logic to decide wether your views has to be refreshed or not. This also applies to plain Android.